# How do you rank based on a measure referencing two tables in a star schema?

Tags: powerbi, dax, rank

I have a star schema data model. DimDate, DimBranchName, BranchActual, BranchBudget.

I have measures to calculate the YTD variance to Budget by Branch called QVar. Qvar takes the counts from BranchActual and compares it BranchBudget between two dates. The visual is controlled by DimBranchName and DimDate.

Current Result:

```
BranchName    YTDActual    YTDBudget    QVar
A             100          150          (33%)
B             200          200           0.0%
C             25           15            66%
```

I want a measure to be able to rank DimBranchName[BranchName] by QVar that will interact with the filters I have in place.

Desired result:

```
BranchName    YTDActual    YTDBudget    QVar     Rank
A             100          150          (33%)     3
B             200          200           0.0%     2
C             25           15            66%      1
```

What I've tried so far is

```
R Rank of Actual v Goal = 
var V = [QVar]
RETURN
RANKX(ALLSELECTED('BranchActual'),CALCULATE(V),,ASC,Dense)
```

What I get is all 1's

```
BranchName    YTDActual    YTDBudget    QVar     Rank
A             100          150          (33%)     1
B             200          200           0.0%     1
C             25           15            66%      1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare a variable it is computed once and treated as a constant through the rest of your DAX code, so `CALCULATE(V)` is simply whatever `V` was when you declared the variable.

This might be closer to what you want:

```
R Rank of Actual v Goal =
RANKX ( ALLSELECTED ( DimBranchName[BranchName] ), [QVar],, ASC, DENSE )
```

This way `[QVar]` is called within the filter context of the `BranchName` instead of being a constant. (Note that referencing a measure within another measure implicitly wraps it in `CALCULATE` so you don't need that again.)

Comment: IT WORKED!!!!!!!!!! SUPER EXCITED AND DETAILED EXPLANATION. Thank you muchly!